# I was denied entry to South Korea, How long will it take me travel to Korea or apply for Korean Visa?

Tags: visas

I am a Liberian. Citizens of my country have had visa upon arrival (90 days) with South Korea. Upon my arrival in May 2018 I was denied entry.
How Long will it take me to travel to Korea or apply for Korean visa?

Comment: Do you mean how long do you have to wait? What was the reason for the entry denial?